# Flask: get uploaded image size and delete at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a small Flask web application . I have uploaded images in media/upload_images folder .Now I want to get the uploaded image size when I will click a button in client side and  after getting the image size, meanwhile it will be aslo deleted from media/upload_images folder. How can I implement this? ... Any suggestion? Help will be appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to import `os` module.

```py
import os
```

To get the size of an uploaded file you can use like below:

```py
os.stat('media/upload_images/filename.extension').st_size # This will give you the size in bytes.
```

To remove a file, you can use like below:

```py
os.remove('media/upload_images/filename.extension')
```

I will suggest you, when you are deleting a file, do the proper error handling to avoid exceptions.

**Update:**
To get the size of each file in a directory:

```py
files_list = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'])
for file in files_list:
    size = os.stat(app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] + file)
    print('Filename: ', file, ', Size: ', size)
```

Comment: It is difficult to tell without code that you have implemented. Could you post the code?

Comment: actually im trying to get all image size in my flask web app
check this : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X392qqbgvb/

Comment: `app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST']` contains the directory of the uploaded images, right? Then you need to concat your perticular filename, along with it's extension to get the exact file path.

Comment: Looking at your code looks like you want to delete all the files within that directory? Is that true?

Comment: can you able to give me a code example for contatenation .. That will help me a lot

Comment: deleting is not major issue .. If can do this I can also delete ..

Comment: If `app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST']` contains the directory of the uploaded images' directory, and you want to find the size of `image1.png` file, then you can do like this: `os.stat(app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST']+'image1.png').st_size`.

Comment: I meant, you want to find the size of all the files with in that directory? That's why you are using `os.listdir()` method?

Comment: Oh, it was not mentioned in OP. Then you are applying in wrong place. I have updated the answer.

Comment: issue sol ved .. Thanks

Comment: Good, then you can accept it as answer and upvote it.